# JavaScript parse Error

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.1

I am using `laravel 5.1` PHP framework and a sign chart from a javascript, But when i send data from controller with ' (single quote) but JavaScript Parse as some undefined value
 `$data_B_Temp = "{x : new Date('".$piecesTime[$dataLength]."'), y :".$pieces[$dataLength]."}";`

this variable will make a graph point input
as

```
$(function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("TempChart",
{


  axisX:{
    title: "time",
    gridThickness: 2,
    interval:1,
    intervalType: "hour",
    valueFormatString: "hh TT K",
    labelAngle: -10
  },
  axisY:{
    title: "distance"
  },
  data: [
  {
    type: "line",
   dataPoints:[{{$data_B_Temp }}]

  }
  ]
});

$("#TempChart").CanvasJSChart(chart.render());


});
```

But the javascript executes as  :

```
dataPoints:[{x : new Date(&#039;2015-10-30 18:16:08&#039;), y :38.5}]
```

I'm confused `&#039` is coming? how to solve it?

Comment: Try `{!! $data_B_Temp !!}` instead; dataPoints is getting escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Laravel Blade documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#displaying-data), using `{{ }}` results in an escaped string, which would cause the behavior that you're seeing.

Try using `{!! !!}` instead; using that syntax will tell Blade to not escape the string.

```
...
dataPoints: [{!! $data_B_Temp !!}]
...
```