# Chartist import graph data from database in laravel

Tags: html, laravel, charts, chartist.js

i have data in sql database, how to get them and place in the chartist as line graph data? 
 
so far, i've passed the data through controller into blade in a parameter, and i don't know how to implement it in chartist. Thanks!

Comment: It's depends on, what kind of chart you are preparing, like pie chart, bar chart, line graph etc. You need to more specific. because `chart.js` take different style inputs to represent it.

Comment: i want to use line graph, sorry for not to be specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`Chart.js`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html) you can easily make a static line chart it. Look here

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script async="" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.js"></script>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

But if you have to make a dynamic chart according to your database then what you have to do? Here, if you can change the data array then you will be able to prepare your own chart. I have asked a same question once in `stackoverflow`, finally I got a solution by myself.

So what you need to do? I hope you are familiar with `laravel` blade. I mean how to write a laravel variable inside a JS file. So you need to make a string of you dataset. You must make a string like this data set from your controller and pass it to the view, this way

```
$points = "[12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]"
```

Later will put the variable in the position of the data array inside the `javascript` in `blade`. Like

```
data: {! $points !},
```

If you do this I hope your chart will definitely appear. In this case you can take the help from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33441211/javascript-parse-error). Otherwise you will face same parsing problem like I had faced.

Additionally you can change the `labels` here by applying same procedure

Comment: great it works thanks! but there's one more problem, do you know the command for passing only database value into view? my command didn't pass only the value, but whole data including the coloumn name, the output was like : data: [{"progress":20},{"progress":40},{"progress":30}] (*ps progress is the coloumn name)

Comment: sorry, i forgot to use pluck method, problem solved! thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah, that's possible too.